# Rails 4: What is is good multi-select plugin that is functional on mobile devices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-select

I am looking for a good Rails 4 solution to the following.

I want to create a tag system for posts, much the same as you can see here on stackoverflow. Acts_as_taggable seems to be the best option. The problem is this:

I want to have my own database of tags that the user can select from (i.e. no users can create their own tags). Therefore a select box is needed. BUT this select box needs to be a multiselect so that multiple tags can bee added to a post AND it needs to be functional on mobile devices. This makes the jQuery plugin Chosen unsuitable as it just doesn't work on mobile devices.

Suggestions please?

Comment: HABTM or has many through with a tag model using [collection check boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

Answer (score 1):

[Select2](https://select2.github.io/) is one solution for this (see [the examples page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)). Allows multi-select from a list of options with very little effort. And there's a rails gem that packages it up for you: https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails

Comment: @user1271772 I feel for you but I cannot commit since I don’t know anything about the subject. Nor do I know anyone that does. Wish I could help (legitimately).

Comment: Gotcha. I committed. 